# Letsencrypt. Challenges pending with one of three domains

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, cert-manager

I recently added a new domain (managed in aws route 53) to my portfolio. Now I am using a Kubernetes cluster and the cert manager to manage my certificates with letsencrypt. Basically this is my setup

- Cert Manager installed in namespace cluster-manager (as described in [cert manager documentation](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) with helm)
- ClusterIssuer using an htt01 -> ingress -> nginx solver
- Ingress with my currently 3 hosts

Now my problem is that for one of the 3 domains my order with letsencrypt is stuck in pending. Describing the order gives me the following output

```
#...
Challenges:
      Token:        my-token
      Type:         http-01
      URL:          https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/xxxx/yyyy
      Token:        my-token
      Type:         dns-01
      URL:          https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/xxxx/yyyy
      Token:        my-token
      Type:         tls-alpn-01
      URL:          https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/xxxx/yyyy
    Identifier:     my-domain.com
    Initial State:  pending
    URL:            https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/xxxx
    Wildcard:       false
```

My already present domains both are presented with initial state valid and if I remove the new domain certificates are issued as expected.

After alot of digging I have now run out of ideas what the problem could be.

- my-host:80/.well-known/acme-challence/my-token is reachable
- i disabled ssl redirect to exclude a permanent redirect as the problem
- all three cert manager pods are running as expected

I didn't want to post all yaml files and logs as this would make this question explode but I'd be more than happy to update the answer with information that might be helpful.

Comment: Have you checked the logs of the cert-manager pod?

Comment: yes. they didn't show any unusual stuff as far as i remember. I can update the question soon. but it seems that now I killed my solver service so I need to get that back in place before the logs are helping with the original problem.

Comment: ok and now everything worked after multiple removals of my helm application as well as the cert manager. Pretty unsatisfiying because I don't know what I did differently. Now the order went through successfull. I will investigate what I did differently because now I have no idea what I'm gonna do if I face the same problem also I cannot really answer this question

Comment: I've faced a similar issue before. For me, deleting and re-creating the ingress resource solved it, but I, too, was quite unsatisfied with it because I nevet got around to actually understand what had gone wrong in the first place.